# RealEditText behaves like TextView (Compatibility with Eclipse)

Tags: java, android, eclipse, gradle

I'm using [RealTextView](https://github.com/skimarxall/RealTextView) library and I face the following problem. First let me say, I would gladly use this in *Android Studio* (and gradle).
Yet, I have project in *Eclipse* that has the need of the RealEditText view properties. I've tried *manual import of the library and the RealEditText behaves like TextView.

in my layout.xml:

```
<com.myapplication.view.RealEditText
 android:id="@+id/realEditText1"
android:layout_width="400dp"
android:layout_height="300dp"
android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView1"
android:ems="10"
real:minTextSize="18sp"
android:text="RealEditText" />
```

And then referencing it in the activity/fragment (pretty common practice, nothing fancy happening here).

```
private RealEditText mRealEText;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mRealEText = (RealEditText) findViewById(R.id.realEditText1);

}
```

I also tried adding the property `android:editable="true"` to the view, but it made no difference. Anyone has tried importing this library to Eclipse? Any ideas why this happens?

***copied the lib package (without the checkbox and button views), updated the attr.xml with the lib data**

---

**EDIT:**

Solution to this issue is enabling touch properties in the widget declaration:

```
android:focusable="true"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
```

Comment: Are you using sdk version >= 14?

Comment: yup 
<uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="16"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />